# Jmockit 0.99x issue with IntelliJ IDEA - unexpected exception (works in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, intellij-idea, jmockit

I have a very weird issue with testing in IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.4. Whenever I try to run a test that calls `Mockit.setUpMocks()`, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.setgen.core.ApplicationException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:287)
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:281)
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:267)
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:216)
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:209)
at mockit.Mockit.setUpMocks(Mockit.java:329)
```

However, the same test works just fine when running out of Eclipse. I am 100% certain that my classpath is correct, as it matches my coworkers'. They can run the very same tests just fine. No one knows why I cannot after spending much time trying to figure out what's going on.

I have tried installing different versions of IntelliJ IDEA, configuring the classpath a different way, and a bunch of other methods, but nothing seems to solve the problem.

If it helps, I use Windows 7. Some of my coworkers use it as well, while others use Linux. One other person has the same issue as me.

Thank you for your help!